# How to avoid url Redirection when Crul using php?

Tags: php, web-crawler, crud

I want to crawl a company's LinkedIn profile without using API. I am getting a page redirection while crawling when using the following code.

http://localnew/comapny gets redirected to http://linkedin/company. How to prevent it.

```
 <?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
$cookie_file = "cookies.txt";
$url = 'https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/searchRefresh?keywords=Engineer&location=United%20States&locationId=us:0&refreshType=fullpage&trk=jobs_jserp_search_button_execute&searchOrigin=JSERP&applyLogin=';
$c = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, 1);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:17.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/17.0");
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
$z = curl_getinfo($c);
$s = curl_exec($c);
curl_close($c);
echo "<pre>";print_r($s);exit;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is hard to understand. But I'll do my best.

Possible Reasons for your case:

- They detect your request as a **non-real** person. It's common for big sites to block Spiders/Crawlers.
- The IP used, is from a **Hosting Company**. Usually these are blacklisted.
- The requested is not detected as a **Logged In** User. A Valid Cookie File could fix this.

My recommendation would be switching to their real API.

Comment: Thanks @ubj.i'm new to php.Can you please suggest me how to prevent redirecting page when scraping.The API of LinkedIn is not build for that, so I have to do this with PHP. If there are any other options, please let me know...